# I have multiple "quantity" textboxes, how do I post values of all textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I get the entered values of textboxes to post to my controller with values. Thought of using arrays but have no idea where to start. Textboxes are dynamic due to each have counter number

```
 @{
                var counter = 0;
                foreach (var addedProduct in Model)
                {
                    counter++;
                <tr class="default" data-ng-controller="deleteItemsController">
                    <td>@addedProduct.name</td>
                    <td>@addedProduct.price</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="quantity_@counter" name="quantity_@counter"/>                       
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }                                                           
            }
            <tr>
                <td><b>Total:</b>{{@ViewBag.total}}</td>
                <td>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Payment"))
                    {
                        //how do i get quantity values//
                        <input type="submit" value="pay">
                    }
                </td>
```

my model:

```
public class ProductVar
{
    public int productID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}
```

I have not implemented method yet, trying to figure out how to post all values first.

Comment: Can you show your model and controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close. Read [`this blog post`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) from Phil Haack and things will be clear how your input fields should be named. You will understand how model binding works in ASP.NET MVC as well.

Also you should place your `<input>` fields inside the HTML `<form>` or nothing will ever be sent to the server when this form gets submitted.

So start by modifying your view code so that you use strongly typed HTML helpers for generating your input fields. They will take car of properly naming them:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Payment"))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr class="default" data-ng-controller="deleteItemsController">
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].price)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x[i].quantity)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Total:</b>
            @ViewBag.total
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="pay" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Now you can have your controller action that will be triggered when the form is submitted:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ProductVar[] model)
{
    ...
}
```

In this example only the `quantity` field of the model will be sent to the server because that's the only input field present inside the HTML form and so the only values sent to the server. If you want to bind the other values you might include them as hidden fields as well:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].name)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].price)
```

Of course in most cases this is bad practice because the user can manipulate those values. The best approach is to retrieve them from the db in your POST action using the same id that you used to retrieve them in the GET action that you used to render this form.